# Select from WHERE query not working

Tags: php, mysql

Thank you everyone for your answers. It was bang on. I changed the spelling and now it is working - it displays the records for the specific user's account.  The problem now is that it doesn't execute the query but I'll create a new question for that to avoid confusion.

THANKS AGAIN EVERYONE FOR YOUR HELP :)

---

I'm completely self-made in this area and the moment something doesn't work I don't know where to even look.  I was wondering if anyone can spot what's making this code not work.

At the moment I've got a very simple query where users on my site can see their billing history summary on a table.  I would like them to be able to click on an row to have a full invoice displayed but it's not happening.  I took a code that can make such query, but the moment I add where uid=' and paid=Y things stop working.

This is the code. Can anyone spot the mistake?

Thanks!!!
Eugenie

```
<?php

include("mainfile.php");
include(XOOPS_ROOT_PATH."/header.php");


$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db name"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="tbl name"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name  WHERE uid='";
$Sql=$Sql .  $xoopsUser->uid("s") . "'  AND Paid='Y'";


$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Billing Date</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Invoice Number</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Description</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Total GBP</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>View</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['date']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['TicketID']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['project']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['grandTotal']; ?></td>


<td align="center"><a href="http://website.co.uk/site/viewInvoice.php?TicketID=<? echo     $rows['TicketID']; ?>">View</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
mysql_close();
include(XOOPS_ROOT_PATH."/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Edit this:`$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password); 
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link)or die("cannot select DB");`

Comment: Nice one!! It did it. thanks :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP variables are case sensitive. You're using $sql, then $Sql.

Try:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name  WHERE uid='";
$sql = $sql .  $xoopsUser->uid("s") . "'  AND Paid='Y'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add like

```
$Sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name  WHERE uid='" .$xoopsUser->uid("s") . "'  AND Paid='Y'";
```

And its a problem with the variable you are using .Try this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name  WHERE uid='";
$Sql=$sql .  $xoopsUser->uid("s") . "'  AND Paid='Y'";
```

Use small 's'

Answer (score 0):

What Gautam said, but also, as a comment to what you were trying to do: you put

```
$Sql = $Sql . 'blah blah blah';
```

instead of

```
$Sql = $sql . 'stuff'
```

which was the original variable for your query. Either way, it makes more sense to just put it into one variable straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Edit and Try this:

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link)or die("cannot select DB");
```

&

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name  WHERE uid='".$xoopsUser->uid('s')."'  AND Paid='Y'";
```